# Log into an https site using perl

Tags: javascript, perl, authentication, https, mechanize

I'm trying to write a perl script to log into a password protected site. I've used the WWW::Mechanize module for similar tasks in the past, but this this site is different in a couple of ways:

-It uses javascript on the protected pages so mechanize won't work. I'd prefer to implement something with headless browser as the script runs hourly on my work machine.

-It has no login form, rather the browser displays a popup box to log in and I can't for the life of me figure out how to deal with it.

The url:https://fwxwww2.hpr.for.gov.bc.ca/Scripts/Public/Common/Report.asp?Report=Hourly

I've found enough good resources for how to proceed with the javascript after logging in, so it's really just how to authenticate that's got me stumped. Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to approach this. I'm open to solutions that don't involve perl, but I'm running cygwin so options are somewhat limited.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Data::Dumper;

my $url= 'https://fwxwww2.hpr.for.gov.bc.ca/Scripts/Public/Common/Report.asp?Report=Hourly';
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );
$mech->credentials(
    'myusername',
    'mypassword'
);
$mech->get( $url );
print $mech->content();
```

Comment: credentials() takes four arguments.  See [this thread which includes sample code](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=437928).

Comment: Cheers. The mechanize [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech->credentials(_$username,_$password_)) indicates that 2 arguments are also acceptable.

Comment: Ah, I beg your pardon.  Didn't realize they had expanded that functionality.

Comment: If you do `cpan -l|grep Mechanize`, what version does it report (current is 1.72, I think)?  Can you try `cpan` and then `cpan> install WWW::Mechanize` to update the module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the browser displays a popup box

This is HTTP authentication, described in [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) and documented in the method `credentials` in [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize#mech-credentials-username-password-) and [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent#ua-credentials-netloc-realm-).

I see no JavaScript involved. Maybe only in the documents after authentication. See my [documentation improvement for JS-enabled Mech-workalikes](https://github.com/daxim/www-mechanize/commit/6d73a0ad269c6b3886e90237300beec6b7f730a4#L1R82).

---

**edit:**

[Antonio Dolcetta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9325706) gives the hint that the NTLM authentication scheme is used. Upgrade your version of [Authen::NTLM](http://p3rl.org/Authen::NTLM). As per the [LWP::Authen::Ntlm](http://p3rl.org/LWP::Authen::Ntlm) documentation, enable keep-alive and use the correct notation for netloc (including port number) and username (including NT domain name).

Comment: Thanks, I've tried a few permutations using the credentials method but keep getting the message _Unauthorized at ./mech_test.pl line 14_. Added some sample code to the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that website is using NTLM to authenticate.
Make sure you have LWP::Authen::Ntlm installed.
Try something like this (this example uses LWP::UserAgent instead of WWW::Mechanize, but should be the same)

Also see: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=642656

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url = 'https://fwxwww2.hpr.for.gov.bc.ca/Scripts/Public/Common/Report.asp?Report=Hourly';
# important to use keep_alive for NTLM
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive=>1);
$ua->credentials('fwxwww2.hpr.for.gov.bc.ca', '', 'username', 'password');

my $response = $ua->get($url);
print  $response->content();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - definitely got me pointed in a better direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use firefox with live http headers plugin enabled.

This way you could see what information going in and out and you are able to replicate it.

It is possible that this page checks other things to disallow bots, like browser version detection, javascript detection and so on.

Also your $url contains a \t character.